# WakeLock.acquire takes long time on Samsung Galaxy SII LTE

Tags: galaxy, wakelock

In my project, another thread will be launched in the service. To avoid this thread be paused when device suspend, I acquired the WakeLock before launch this thread and release this WakeLock after this thread is finished.
Sometimes, This API call (WakeLock.acquire) takes too long time, over 4 minutes on Samsung Galaxy SII LTE.

Below is my code:
In service onStartCommand, acquire wake lock:

```
    if (mWakeLock == null) {
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Eca Engine");
        mWakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
    }
    if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Before acquire");
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        Log.d(TAG, "After acquire");
    }
    ......
```

In thread, release wake lock:

```
    if (mWakeLock != null && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
```

the log: "After acquire" printed after "Before acquire" over 4 minutes.

The test device information is:
Model number: Sc-03d
Android version: 2.3.6
Based version: 3c03domlb9
Kernel version: 2.6.35.11 - 3c03domlb9 980106 se.infra@sep-53#2
Build number: gingerbread omlb9

Did any one meet this issue before? Or any suggest for me is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem.
I send a command to the main thread to let it release wake lock instead of release it directly in the new thread. Then this issue can't reproduce anymore.

Does anyone understand the root cause? Why we can not acquire the wake lock in service main thread and release it in another thread even we operate on the same WakeLock obj.

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue reproduced again. I have checked on Sharp device, it doesn't occur. This issue only occurs on Samsung Galaxy SII device.